# Loop not iterating full length

Tags: java, android, hashmap, iteration

I'm passing a String to a method that has commas in as delimiters.

```
"TMJ,Emma,Sarah"
```

I tokenize this String using ',' as the regular expression to split.

I then iterate the length of the tokenized array comparing each element against a HashMap of all possible values. If the value being tested is a key in the HashMap then i get the key's value and store that in another String.

I want to append each value of the key to the String that holds the values.

It seems to iterate only once, then jumps out of the loop and returns only the first thing it finds in the hashmap.

Could anyone explain why? Thanks in advance Matt.

```
public static String getrecipientIntergerValues(String recipient) {

        Log.e(TAG, "recipient string list passed in to app obj = " + recipient);


         String[] tokenizedRecipient = recipient.split(",");
         String recipientAsInteger = "";

         for(int i = 0; i < tokenizedRecipient.length; i++){
             Log.e(TAG, "tokenizedRecipient = " + tokenizedRecipient[i].toString());
         }

         Log.e(TAG, "tokenizedRecipient length = " + tokenizedRecipient.length);

         for(int i = 0; i < tokenizedRecipient.length; i++){



             if(recipients.containsKey(tokenizedRecipient[i].toString())){
                 Log.e(TAG, "hashmap contains key " + tokenizedRecipient[i].toString() + "with value " + recipients.get(tokenizedRecipient[i].toString()));
                 String integerValueOfName = recipients.get(tokenizedRecipient[i].toString());
                 recipientAsInteger = recipientAsInteger + integerValueOfName + ",";

             }

         }

        Log.e(TAG, "recipient list as integers = " + recipientAsInteger);

        return recipientAsInteger;
    }
```

.

```
09-20 16:33:51.039: E/NfcScannerApplication(25835): recipient string list passed in to app obj = Emma, TMJ, 
09-20 16:33:51.039: E/NfcScannerApplication(25835): tokenizedRecipient = Emma
09-20 16:33:51.064: E/NfcScannerApplication(25835): tokenizedRecipient =  TMJ
09-20 16:33:51.064: E/NfcScannerApplication(25835): tokenizedRecipient =  
09-20 16:33:51.079: E/NfcScannerApplication(25835): tokenizedRecipient length = 3
09-20 16:33:51.079: E/NfcScannerApplication(25835): hashmap contains key Emmawith value 3
09-20 16:33:51.089: E/NfcScannerApplication(25835): recipient list as integers = 3,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing what `recipients` contains, you can safely assume that

```
if(recipients.containsKey(tokenizedRecipient[i].toString())){
    Log.e(TAG, "hashmap contains key " + tokenizedRecipient[i].toString() + "with value " + recipients.get(tokenizedRecipient[i].toString()));
    String integerValueOfName = recipients.get(tokenizedRecipient[i].toString());
    recipientAsInteger = recipientAsInteger + integerValueOfName + ",";
}
```

only executes once because `recipients` only contains a key for `Emma`. The `for` loop loops 3 times, but only matches the `if` once.

If your `recipients` map contains keys for `Emma` and `TMJ` then you're problem is your `split()` method, take a look at the other answers.

Comment: Hi, i've posted a log. I pass in Emma and TMJ. So there are definately 2 keys

Comment: @turtleboy Yes `recipient` holds `"Emma, TMJ,"`, but the `recipients` (note the s) map might not.

Comment: @turtleboy But your log doesn't say what happens if `recipients.containsKey(...)` returns `false`.  You might want to add an `else` at the end of this `if` to write something to the log file to see what's happening.  Your code looks fine, I don't think it's exiting the loop prematurely.  I think it's just not finding TMJ in your map.

Comment: Ooops, wait a minute.  If your string is "Emma, TMJ," then it will try to search for `" TMJ"`, not `"TMJ"`.  The extra space will cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your logging suggests that the string you are passing is `"Emma, TMJ, "` which is not what you suggest.

```
09-20 16:33:51.039: ... recipient string list passed in to app obj = Emma, TMJ,
```

I believe the solution to your problem would be to use `String.split(",",0)` as this will remove empty strings at the end. You may also wish to use `String.trim()` before looking up the string in your map.

Answer (score 0):

If the input string is `"Emma, TMJ,"` then the `split` will return an array containing these two strings:

```
"Emma"
" TMJ"
```

The last one will not match `"TMJ"`.  Try using `", *"` (or, better, `"\\s*,\\s*"`) as the regex to use for `split` (this will treat extra spaces as part of the delimiter and not include them in the resulting strings); or use the `.trim()` method on the resulting strings (which removes leading and trailing whitespace).